# How to draw Latex multiple bar chart with error bar

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, bar-chart

Can someone help me with putting error bars on multiple bar graphs. This is what I currently have and it doesn't look any good, so far :(

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Accuracy,
enlargelimits=0.05,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar interval=0.7,
]

\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,80) +- (0.0, 0.5)
    (2,81) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (3,90) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (4,92) +- (0.0, 0.6)
    (5,93) +- (0.0, 0.9)};
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,90) +- (0.0, 0.5)
    (2,86) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (3,80) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (4,82) +- (0.0, 0.6)
    (5,83) +- (0.0, 0.9)};
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,80) +- (0.0, 0.5)
    (2,81) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (3,90) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (4,92) +- (0.0, 0.6)
    (5,93) +- (0.0, 0.9)};
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,90) +- (0.0, 0.5)
    (2,86) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (3,80) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (4,82) +- (0.0, 0.6)
    (5,83) +- (0.0, 0.9)};
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,90) +- (0.0, 0.5)
    (2,86) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (3,80) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (4,82) +- (0.0, 0.6)
    (5,83) +- (0.0, 0.9)};
\legend{A,B,C,D,E}
%\draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange! Could you please provide us a complete Minimal Working Example, so that we can understand in what environment you're working on? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error bars aren't aligned with the bars because you're using the `ybar interval` plot style. I guess this would count as a missing feature, but in your case, you shouldn't actually be using `ybar interval` anyway, but simply `ybar`, since you're not trying to plot bars with different data dependent widths.

To get a decent looking plot, you can try the following:

- Set `ybar=0pt` to remove the gaps within the groups.
- Set `enlargelimits={abs=0.5}` to set the margin on the outside of the plot to be equal to half the distance between the categories. This requires a recent version of PGFPlots, and requires setting `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}` or newer in the preamble.
- Set `bar width=0.15` (or some other value that's smaller than `0.2`) to make the bars thin enough to create a gap between the groups. With five bars per group, setting the value to `0.2` would result in all the bars sitting flush next to each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend pos=outer north east,
enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
ybar=0pt,
bar width=0.15,
xtick={0.5,1.5,...,5.5},
xticklabels={1,...,5},
x tick label as interval
]

\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,80) +- (0.0, 0.5)
    (2,81) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (3,90) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (4,92) +- (0.0, 0.6)
    (5,93) +- (0.0, 0.9)};
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,90) +- (0.0, 0.5)
    (2,86) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (3,80) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (4,82) +- (0.0, 0.6)
    (5,83) +- (0.0, 0.9)};
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,80) +- (0.0, 0.5)
    (2,81) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (3,90) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (4,92) +- (0.0, 0.6)
    (5,93) +- (0.0, 0.9)};
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,90) +- (0.0, 0.5)
    (2,86) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (3,80) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (4,82) +- (0.0, 0.6)
    (5,83) +- (0.0, 0.9)};
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,90) +- (0.0, 0.5)
    (2,86) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (3,80) +- (0.0, 1.5)
    (4,82) +- (0.0, 0.6)
    (5,83) +- (0.0, 0.9)};
\legend{A,B,C,D,E}
%\draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. Now, on the x-axis, instead of the numbers pointing to the middle bar, can I put lines to separate the groups and then remove the tick pointer above the numbers.

Comment: Sorry, talked too soon. The \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10} is causing an error on my MikTex 2.9 compilation. Let me play around with it for a moment.

Comment: @tx008l: Actually, `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}` or newer works as well. If your version of PGFPlots is older than that, you should definitely update it. I also edited my answer to show a way to get the interval labels, but it's a bit manual.

Comment: Thanx; I needed to upgrade. Worked perfectly with \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}. Thanx again for the excellent prompt response.