# Drawing Bar charts with Std.deviation and Confd.level with PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to draw a bar chart where on each bar it shows the standard deviation(and also confidence level). I tried using following [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199142/how-to-draw-latex-multiple-bar-chart-with-error-bar) but I get the "dimension too large" error. Basically I have data as such:

```
  Label  Mean    Std.dev  Confd.Level
  l1      value   value    value
  l2      value   value    value
```

I tried different ways, couldn't solve it. The current one that throws error looks as such:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend pos=outer north east,
enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
ybar=0pt,
bar width=0.15,
xtick={0.000,...,0.0045},
xticklabels={Light, Medium, Heavy},
x tick label as interval
]

\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {
    (1,0.0030977691) +- (1.92E-004,1.92E-004)
    (1,0.0030376050) +- (1.77E-004,1.77E-004)
    (1,0.0029500634) +- (1.58E-004,1.58E-004)
    (1,0.0029072753) +- (1.48E-004,1.48E-004)};


%\legend{A,B,C,D}
%\draw ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:0,0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The error is caused by the line `enlargelimits={abs=0.5}`, which adds to *all* for axis limits (`xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`) a value of 0.5. But because your y values are so small, 0.5 is a "large value" ... After resolving this issue it should be quite easy to accomplish what you want, right? Please let us know, if this solves your question or if you need further assistance.